# Android: Service crashed after closing the app

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started learning writing a Service yesterday, and here I have a service, which I expect to run all the time even if my App terminates. This service has a listener on my Firebase database and generates Notifications if the data has changed.

What confused me was that my service could run successfully ONLY IF the app was running. Immediately after I closed the app, my phone alerted me that "Unfortunately, this app has stopped (crashed)". The alert came two times and then the service never restarted (I guess).

I couldn't figure out why my service crashed after closing the App. I started the Service in the OnCreate method in MainActivity. And here's the whole service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
private static DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private static String uid;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static int notification_id=0;
private static boolean launched=false;
public MyService(){}
@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    if(!launched)
    {
        launched=true;
        databaseReference=MainActivity.databaseReference;
        uid=MainActivity.uid;
        sharedPreferences=MainActivity.sharedPreferences;
        databaseReference.child("users").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                MyData myData=dataSnapshot.getValue(MyData.class);
                if(myData!=null)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> myGroups=myData.getGroups();
                    for(String group_id:myGroups)
                    {
                        if(group_record_listener!=null)databaseReference.child("group_records").child(group_id).removeEventListener(group_record_listener);
                        databaseReference.child("group_records").child(group_id).addValueEventListener(group_record_listener);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
                System.out.println(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
private ValueEventListener group_record_listener=new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        final String group_id=dataSnapshot.getKey();
        Query lastQuery=databaseReference.child("group_records").child(group_id).child("records").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
        lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    final Record new_record=childSnapshot.getValue(Record.class);
                    if(new_record!=null)
                    {
                        if((new_record.getType()==1)&&new_record.getTo_name().equals(sharedPreferences.getString("name","")))
                        {
                            if(group_record_listener!=null)databaseReference.child("group_records").child(group_id).removeEventListener(group_record_listener);
                        }
                        if(!new_record.getOperator().equals(sharedPreferences.getString("name","")))
                        {
                            databaseReference.child("groups").child(group_id).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                            {
                                @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                {
                                    String group_name=(String)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                    generateNotification(new_record,group_name);
                                }
                                @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){}
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){}
        });
    }
    @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
        System.out.println(databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
private void generateNotification(Record record,String group_name)
{
    String str="";
    switch (record.getType())
    {
        //. . . determine str
    }
    Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("group \""+group_name+"\"")
            .setContentText(str)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();
    NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification_id++;
    manager.notify(notification_id,notification);
}
@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

If you have any idea, please help. Thanks in advance~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service uses static members from `MainActivity`: `databaseReference`, `uid` and `sharedPreferences`.  As you explain in your post, the service is started from `MainActivity.onCreate()`.  In that case, `databaseReference`, `uid` and `sharedPreferences` have (presumably) been initialized and have valid values.

The `onStartCommand()` method in the service returns `START_STICKY`.  If your app is killed, for example, if you put it in the background and then swipe it from the recent tasks list, the process for the app is destroyed and then, because your service is `START_STICKY`, the system creates a new instance of the app (new process).  This new instance contains the service component, but no valid instance of `MainActivity`.  The static members of `MainActivity` will have default values.  In particular, `uid` will be null, which will cause an exception when you call `databaseReference.child("users").child(uid)`.  You could confirm this is happening by adding debug logging to output the values of `uid` and `sharedPreferences`.

But before spending a lot of effort trying to make this work, be aware that the current design is a battery-killer.  Having a service running all the time with an active listener on the database requires that Firebase maintain a network connection to the database.  I don't know what your database monitoring requirements are, but it's usually better for cases like this to have server-side processing the monitors changes (e.g. a Cloud Function) and sends FCM messages to the users that need to be notified.

Comment: Thank u for the detailed explanation~ I will look for FCM messages soon. But other than that, I wonder is there any way to keep the uid value and pass it to the new service instance?

Comment: @Einsambr: Instead of static members on MainActivity, pass the data you need in the `Intent` used for `startService()` and available as a parameter of `onStartCommand()`.  `Service` extends `Context`, so you can `getSharedPreferences()` and don't need to pass them in the intent.  Instead of START_STICKY.  I think you want to return [START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) to cause the intent containing the start data again when the service is restarted.